# Multiple progress bar status with one XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Trying to get multiple progress bars status with one XMLHttpRequest with a multifile upload. Cannot use jQuery and I do not have the option to loop through files and have the `new XMLHttpRequests` inside the loop due to client restrictions.

Currently I can have one progress bar for all files combined. What I need is multiple progress bar percentages. If I do a request.upload.onprogress inside the fileObj loop, then only the last progress bar will be updated.

```
let formData = new FormData(); 
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', postUrl);

for( var x in fileObj){
    formData.append("file", fileObj[x]);

    //this is where I tried to put the request.upload.onprogress with dynamic ids but failed.
}

request.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    d.getElementById("progress-bar" ).style.width = percentComplete + "%";
    d.getElementById('progress-bar-output').innerHTML = Math.round(percentComplete) + "%";              
    }
};

request.onload = function (e) {
    console.log( JSON.parse( e.target.response ) );
};

request.send(formData);
```

Comment: a single XHR has a single progress - you could calculate the upload length of each file and that way you can calculate the individual progress

Comment: is `fileObj` a `FileList` object?

Answer (score 0):

if `fileObj` is a `FileList` object, you could do the following

```
let formData = new FormData(); 
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
let info = [];
let acc = 0;
request.open('POST', postUrl);

for (let x in fileObj){
    const file = fileObj[x];
    formData.append("file", file);

    const cutoff = acc += file.size;
    const index = info.length;
    info.push({cutoff, size: file.size, name: file.name, index});
}


request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        const percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        d.getElementById("progress-bar" ).style.width = percentComplete + "%";
        d.getElementById('progress-bar-output').innerHTML = Math.round(percentComplete) + "%";
        //
        // 
        const file = info.find(({cutoff}) => cutoff <= e.loaded);
        const thisPercentage = 100 * (e.loaded - (file.cutoff - file.size)) / file.size;
        // display file progress here
        // useful info: file.index - i.e. you could show `Uploading File ${file.name} ... ${file.index + 1} of ${info.length}`
    }
});

request.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
    console.log( JSON.parse( e.target.response ) );
};

request.send(formData);
```